# Extract coefficients of SymPy expression containing Derivative

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I have the following expression:

```
T = 0.5*m*(r(t)**2*Derivative(theta(t), t)**2 + Derivative(r(t), t)**2)
```

I would like to extract the coefficients of Derivative(theta(t), t) and Derivative(r(t), t) to get:
`0.5*m*r(t)**2` and `0.5*m`, respectively.

I tried:

```
cr = T.coeff(Derivative(r(t), t),2)
ctheta = T.coeff(Derivative(theta(t), t),2)
```

but I get the following error:

```
'r' object is not callable
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check which version of sympy you are using with `import sympy;print(sympy.__version__)`. You might want to update to version 1.11.1.

```py
from sympy import *
t, m = symbols("t, m")
r, theta = [Function(e) for e in ["r", "theta"]]
T = m / 2 * (r(t)**2 * Derivative(theta(t), t)**2 + Derivative(r(t), t)**2)
```

Let's expand the expression and then call the `coeff` method:

```py
T.expand().coeff(Derivative(r(t), t), 2)
# out: m/2
T.expand().coeff(Derivative(theta(t), t), 2)
# out: m*r(t)**2/2
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I did upgrade to 1.11.1, but I still got the error. The trick however was to express r and theta as Functions (as they are: they depend on t) like you did in the line: r, theta = [Function(e) for e in ["r", "theta"]]